# Android studio package name error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I've imported a project from Eclipse and after sorting through a massive amount of bugs, this is last bug for which I can't find a solution.

At the top of my Java classes I receive an error about my package:

> Package name 'com.example.appname' does not correspond with filepath
>    'androidTest.example.appname'

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your package name from `example.appname` to `com.example.appname` in the `androidTest` source root.

Comment: whats the directory to the androidTest source root

Comment: It should be in `/app/src/androidTest`. It's right next to your `main` folder.

Comment: So just change the name of the androidTest.example.appname folder?